# Existe algum Site/API para hospedar fotos na web?

Tags: javascript, php, upload, cloud

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma API que possibilite hospedar fotos na web.

## Exemplo:

```
cloud.push(arquivo, callback, fail);
```

Vou utilizar essa API com a finalidade de possibilitar os usuários de hospedar imagens para foto de perfil, etc (atualmente faço isso usando base64, mas pega muito espaço).

Gostaria de saber um meio de fazer isto.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://api.imgur.com/) (em inglês) – é o mesmo serviço usado pela Stack Exchange.

Comment: @bfavaretto O campo de resposta fica ali embaixo

Comment: da pra usar o CDN da amazon também, mas não é gratuito.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Ô preguiça de dar mais detalhes... aí fica como comentário mesmo.

Comment: A API do ImgUr ficou bem complicada desde a versão 3...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Além do Flickr, seguem algumas das muitas opções populares:

- **[Imgur](http://imgur.com/)**: Um  serviço extremamente popular ([artigo Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur#Popularity)) para hospedar fotos. Expõe uma [API](https://api.imgur.com/) REST com suporte a JSONP e XML. A API é **gratuita para uso não comercial** e *upload* de até 1250 fotos por dia (veja [limites](https://api.imgur.com/#limits)); também possui [planos comerciais](https://www.mashape.com/imgur/imgur-9#!pricing) entre U$25 e U$500 mensais. Requer cadastro e autenticação (OAuth 2.0).
- **[Uploads.im](http://uploads.im/)**: Serviços russo gratuito e sem limites (além da restrição de tamanho máximo da imagem em 10 MB). Além dos formatos populares para imagens web, aceita PSDs e PDFs. Possui [API](http://uploads.im/apidocs) REST com suporte aos formatos JSON (P), XML, TEXTO ou Redirecionamento (no último após um `POST` a API redireciona para o visualizador de imagens).  Não requer cadastro ou autenticação.
- **[ImageShack](https://imageshack.com/)**: Serviço comercial para upload de imagens e videos (o serviço gratuito foi recentemente descontinuado, mas um *trial* de 30 dias ainda está disponível). Inscrições variam de U$2 a U$100. Expõe [API](https://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/) REST com suporte aos formatos JSON e XML. Requer cadastro, obtenção de chave para acesso e autenticação OAuth 2.0.
- **[Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)**: Serviço de gestão de imagens na nuvem. Possui um plano gratuito (limites: 500 MB de espaço, 50.000 imagens e 1 GB de banda / mês) e [planos comerciais](http://cloudinary.com/pricing) com preços entre U$39 e U$219. Utiliza o Amazon S3 e disponibiliza CDN, serviços de backup automáticos, serviços de manipulação de imagens, efeitos, marca d'água detecção de faces, criação de *sprites*, etc. Possui API REST com autenticação baseada em chaves, além de bibliotecas para várias plataformas (incluindo [PHP](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration)).
- **[Picasa Web](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)** - Serviço do Google para hospedar fotos e vídeos baseado em *feeds*. É gratuito conforme os [limites](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/43879?hl=en) do Picasa Web / Google+ (1GB de armazenamento, sendo que fotos menores do que 2048x204 e / ou vídeos menores do que 15 minutos não consumem espaço para usuários do [Google+](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/1224181)). Espaço extra também pode ser adquirido ([100 GB por $4.99](https://www.google.com/settings/storage)) e o serviço escala facilmente para TBs de armazenamento para aplicações com essa necessidade. Além do acesso direto através do protocolo baseado em *feeds* existem bibliotecas para diversas plataformas, incluindo [PHP](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php) (atualmente apenas para a versão 1.0 da API). Opções de autenticação via OAuth 2.0,  OAuth 1.0 AuthSub ou "instalada" (login / senha).

Outra opção além de implementar um mecanismo para armazenar e recuperar imagens de perfil na mão é utilizar o [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/). O Gravatar permite que o usuário associe uma identidade (incluindo fotos) ao seu endereço de e-mail. Dessa forma sua aplicação passa a ser uma simples consumidora da imagem do perfil do usuário ([veja exemplo de código PHP](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/)).

O mesmo pode ser feito com [Social login](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_login). Sites como [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/), [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) e [Google+](https://plus.google.com/up/search) expõe mecanismos de autenticação e acesso ao perfil do usuário. Bibliotecas como [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) e [Janrain](http://janrain.com/) permitem que usuários do seu site se autentiquem com provedores populares (bem como qualquer outro que suporte [OpenID](http://openid.net/)) e expõem uma API comum para que sua aplicação consuma facilmente informações do usuário (incluindo a foto do perfil) sem que você tenha que se preocupar com detalhes de implementação de cada provedor.

Em suma, existem muitas opções para o que você deseja, porém o primeiro exercício a ser feito (antes de falarmos sobre código) é entender melhor quais são seus reais requisitos e, a partir desses, escolher a melhor solução para sua aplicação.

Comment: Boa resposta! :) Obrigado pelas dicas. Alguém sabe das condições do serviço, i.e., se as imagens passam a ser pertença dos detentores do serviço?

Comment: Oi mOrSa, sobre questões de propriedade intelectual, só lendo os termos de serviço de cada site. Eu não sou nenhum *expert* no assunto, porém na média os sites não te dão nenhuma garantia, pedem para que você faça *upload* apenas de conteúdo legitimamente seu. Geralmente os termos de serviço prevem uma licença gratuita para que o site faça o que bem entender com as imagens, mas isso não significa que a propriedade intelectual deixou de ser sua (apenas significa que você não pode processar o site).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Anthony! É como eu costumo dizer: "Não lêem os contratos depois dá asneira!" :)

Answer (score 6):

Você poderá usar a API do Flickr

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Upload

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

As fotos devem ser POSTadas no seguinte URL:

```
https://up.flickr.com/services/upload/
```

Argumentos

- **photo** -    O arquivo para upload.
- **title** (opcional) -    O título da foto.
- **description** (opcional) -    Uma descrição da foto. Pode conter algum HTML limitado.
- **tags** (opcional) -    Uma lista de tags separadas por espaços para aplicar à foto.
- **is_public**, **is_friend**, **is_family** (opcional) -
  Definir como 0 para não e 1 para sim. Especifica quem pode visualizar a foto.
- **safety_level** (opcional) -    Definir 1 para Seguro, 2 para Moderado, ou 3 para Restrito.
- **content_type** (opcional) -    Definir 1 para Foto, 2 para Captura de tela, ou 3 para Outro
- **hidden** (opcional) -     Definir 1 para mostrar as fotos em todos os resultados de busca, 2 para não mostrar nas buscas públicas.

Comment: pode deixar um exemplo também? =P

Comment: Tutorial Exemplo em php http://davidwalsh.name/flickr-php 
(Upload Photos to Flickr with PHP)

Answer (score 3):

[Imgur](http://api.imgur.com/) é uma opção boa. O link está em inglês, mas aponta para uma biblioteca Python e exemplos Android e JavaScript. A política para uso não-comercial é bem razoável.

Answer (score 3):

Existe o Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service)
É a opção mais utilizada pelo pequenos sites e startups.
Este é um serviço de armazenamento de arquivos online oferecido pela Amazon Web Services, que prover via REST, SOAP e BitTorrent transferências de arquivos públicos.

Este é um serviço pago, porem muito barato, é cobrado algo entorno de **US$0.15** por *gigabyte* transferido por mês.

**Passo a passo de como utilizar o serviço:**

- Como se criar uma conta e armazenar as imagens manualmente.

  - http://awshub.com.br/resources/amazon-web-services-hands-on-s3/
- Como fazer o upload das imagens programaticamente:

  - Exemplo em PHP: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/08/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-php.html
- Como acessar as imagens: (URLs de exemplo)

  - s3.amazonaws.com/seuBucket/suaPasta/seuArquivo.png
  - seuBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/suaPasta/seuArquivo.png