# É possível fazer um sistema de upload de arquivos sem utilizar PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, lado-do-cliente, localstorage

Tenho que fazer um sistema de upload de videos, a principio, sem utilizar o "server side". Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso sem php, utilizando SQLLite ou Local Storage. Já pesquisei em vários sites e não achei muita coisa (e sou meio leiga no assunto).

Comment: upload de arquivos? sem server side!
Vai fazer o upload pra onde?

Você precisa de um servidor para o upload ou usar um repositório tipo dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver

Comment: Pois é! Foi um desafio que um professor me deu.

Comment: Sim, você pode usar ASP.NET ou RUBY

Comment: No caso de imagens: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7182/existe-algum-site-api-para-hospedar-fotos-na-web/7187#7187 (é claro que, mesmo que você acesse esses serviços diretamente no *front-end* através de APIs REST, existe sim um *back-end*, ele só não precisou ser escrito por você).

Answer (score 3):

RemoteStorage é uma API Javascript que utiliza `OAuth` e `Node.JS` e em teoria atende ao seu requisito de solução client-only:
http://remotestorage.io/integrate/

Comment: \o/ vivendo e aprendendo!

Answer (score 1):

Upload seria ação de enviar dados de um computador local para um computador ou servidor remoto.

1 - Poderia ser em rede local.

2 - Dropbox é um serviço para armazenamento e partilha de arquivos. [Usando isso aqui](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver)

3 - Usar um meio de armazenamento em [HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/features/storage), especificamente [aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm), salvando base64 do arquivo.

Solução usa isso [Filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Answer (score 1):

Sim seria possível fazer o upload apenas para Localstorage ou Websql, mas você precisaria tratar a imagem (possivelmente utilizando base64), dessa forma você pode fazer o storage local do base64. Lembrando que o enconde do Base64 é lido apenas por CSS3. O angular tem algumas libs prontas para fazer esse tratamento.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um plugin chamado [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started), com ele você pode fazer requests, porem para "usar apenas javascript" você precisa de alguma API de repositório onde passe apenas parâmetros.
Outra solução seria converter em `base64` (utilizados apenas em navegadores específicos) e guardar em `local storage`, mas um arquivo em base64 é grande e o local storage tem um limite de armazenamento.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível fazer upload para um webserver sem a utilização de uma linguagem `server side`. Você pode simplificar seu trabalho utilizando Apis ou módulos do Servidor Web, mas mesmo assim, será Server Side. Você poderia utilizar `SQLite` para um projeto onde o cliente armazena imagem localmente, e as visualiza. Apenas ele conseguirá isso, pois a imagem não está na internet. Se você deseja isto, recomendo o estudo do uso de `Firebase`+ `Angular`